# Supervisor offered work in lab, I accepted. What are the next steps?

Tags: masters, advisor, research-assistantship

I am looking to join a research MSc this fall and one particular supervisor asked me if I would like to join his lab and I said yes.  I though forgot to ask him what to do next. Do I contact the program and tell them that this supervisor has asked me if I would like to join his lab or wait for him to contact the program,  do the needful and then contact me if accepted? Would it be alright if I send him a mail asking him if I should contact the program informing them that he had asked me if I could join his lab? Please advise.

Comment: If you forgot to ask him, ask him then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If somebody has invited you to join their lab but the next steps for doing that are not clear, it is absolutely appropriate to email them to ask them what the next steps are and what you can do to help the process.

Comment: I'll do that.. Thx